# Помогите разобраться с наследованием классов

Tags: delphi, ооп, delphi-7

Имеется класс `TParent` c заготовкой функции `draw`, выполняющей некоторые действия. Имеется класс `TClass = class(TParent)`, дополняющий функцию `draw` следующим образом:

```
function TClass.draw(): boolean;
begin
    inherited;
    //Тут остальные действия
end;
```

Имеется объект `TList` внутри основного объекта программы, содержащий в себе список объектов любых классов, созданных на основе `TParent`, в том числе, и `TClass`. Этот объект записан внутри класса `TParent`:

```
TParent = class
    objects: TList;
    ...
end;
```

Внутри функции `draw` класса `TParent` выполняется такой код:

```
begin
    for i := 0 to objects.count - 1 do
        TParent(objects[i]).draw();
end;
```

Проблема в том, что если внутри `objects` присутствует объект класса `TClass` (или любого, созданного на основе `TParent`), то его реализация метода `draw` не вызывается - выполняется только тот метод, что записан внутри `TParent`. Как это решается?

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо, в этом и была проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось, у вас в `TParent` и в `TClass` не были проставлены метки разрешающие переопределение (`virtual`) и выполняющие переопределение (`override`).

```
TParent = class
  function Draw: boolean; virtual;

TClass = class(TParent)
  function Draw: boolean; override;
```